# Change div position depending on screen resolution (flexbox?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, flexbox

this is what I am trying to achieve (images added below). I know that this can be done with media queries and its just adding different styles depending on the screen resolution. What i have for now is the smartphone version (presented below).

I cant figure out how i can put those two boxes ABOVE the "mytextbox" div on the version for tablets. I was trying different combinations with grid, pull-right/left etc and it doesnt seem to work. I just started reading about flexbox. Maybe thats an option here? If you have any ideas please help. Thank you!

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="mytextbox" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Text from the box</div>
        <div id="box1" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3 mybox">BOX NAME1</div>
        <div id="box2" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3 mybox">BOX NAME2</div>
        <div id="box3" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3 mybox">BOX NAME3</div>
        <div id="box4" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-3 mybox">BOX NAME4</div>
</div>
```

On tablet:

[image]

On smartphone:

[image]

Comment: I think, *I'm not sure*, `col-xs-3` should be `col-xs-12`

Comment: The code that i added is for smartphone and works fine. I have one row with that huge textbox and then another row of four small divs (thats why each gets col-xs-3). But now i want to have two divs, then that huge textbox div, and then again just two small divs (just like on the first image that i attached).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use flexbox for this, to be precise, the `order` property on flex childs:

```
// Create a flex container
.container {
    display: flex;
    // Force default row wrapping behaviour as bootstrap initially intends.
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#mytextbox {
    // Make it the 3rd item in the container flow
    order: 3;
}

#box1 {
    order: 1;
}

#box2 {
    order: 2;
}

#box3 {
    order: 4;
}

#box4 {
    order: 5;
}

// 768 is the bootstrap small-media breakpoint
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #mytextbox {
        // When there's not enough space, make it the first item again
        order: 1;
    }

    #box1 {
        order: 2;
    }

    #box2 {
        order: 3;
    }

    #box3 {
        order: 4;
    }

    #box4 {
        order: 5;
    }   
}
```

[See it in action on codepen](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/JbMXKw?editors=1100) (because: bootstrap css support)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Works perfectly. Thank you!